# csh: Recognizing known aliases inside a script

Tags: bash, terminal, alias, csh

My problem: I have some alias defined in my terminal. I'm then executing a csh script that needs to use that alias, but it's not recognized.

I understand why it's not recognized, and executing the script with `source` is working. However it's a solution that I can't work with (for all kinds of reasons..)

I can see that in bash, the known solution is to add `shopt -s expand_aliases` to the script. but shopt isn't recognized in csh.

Is there some matching solution? Or any other?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a choice to update the script: Instead of sourcing the entire script, put your alias commands in a file say, .cshalias. Inside your script, at the beginning, add the line to source this alias file: `source .cshalias`.  This should do.

Ideally, the shell script you write should be sourcing 2 alias files inside:the user level file `~/.cshrc` and the systemwide `/etc/csh.cshrc` so that any updates happening in future will get reflected in your script as well. It is also possible that there are some other files where the aliases are defined which you have to find out and source inside your script.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not an option either. The aliases are not defined by me and I can't tell when they might be updated or changed.